# iOS - Using TTTAttributedLabel to set two color text

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm creating iOS app that has a label. I want to set two colors. One for first part and other color for remaining part.
I've seen some messages in Stack over flow that, [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) has the ability to set more than one color to text. My text will be like "ABC > def". For "ABC", i want to set brown color and for "def", i want to set white color.
How can I set that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
NSString* text = @"ABC > def";
attributedLabel = [[[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
attributedLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
attributedLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
attributedLabel.fontColor = [UIColor brownColor];
[attributedLabel setText:text afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
    NSRange whiteRange = [text rangeOfString:@"def"];
    if (whiteRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    // Core Text APIs use C functions without a direct bridge to UIFont. See Apple's "Core Text Programming Guide" to learn how to configure string attributes.
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor range:whiteRange];
    }

    return mutableAttributedString;
}];

[attributedLabel sizeToFit]; //this may not be needed if the frame provided is large enough
```

That searches for "def" in your string and sets the foreground color of the text to white for that range. Hope this helps. I only just learned this yesterday. Came across your question whilst trying to figure it out for myself.

Comment: don't forget to return mutableAttributedString at the end of the block.

Comment: @djibouti33 thanks, don't know how I missed that. Edited the answer to include that now.

Comment: Any one has solution for Swift?

Comment: @guru I could convert this to Swift, but attributedText property is available on UILabel since iOS 6 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620542-attributedtext

Answer (score 6):

You could use TTTRegexAttributedLabel available at : https://github.com/kwent/TTTRegexAttributedLabel. (TTTAttributedLabel based but more easier to use with regular expressions)

```
  //SET FONT ONLY ON FIRST MATCH REGEX
  TTTRegexAttributedLabel *label = [[TTTRegexAttributedLabel alloc] init];
  label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  NSString *s = @"ABC > def";
  [self.label setText:s withFirstMatchRegex:@"^[a-zA-Z ]*>"
                        withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]
                        withColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. My problem solved by using TTTAttributedLabel. In future, I'll keep in mind to use the library that you suggested.