# Search for a string in a string and make it Bold in the original String

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I know how to check if a string (`NSString`) contains another smaller stringFor this m doing like:

```
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
// here I need to make that string bold
}
```

Apart from this I want if I got that string I want to make it bold in the original string.So, is there any way to make my particular String Bold? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: for bold string .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013705/any-way-to-bold-part-of-a-nsstring

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use  NSAttributedString. But problem is displaying NSAttributedString.

In iOS 6.0's label support NSAttributedString but less version will need third party label.

Use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/downloads) link for NSAttributedString.

Refer [ios-using-tttattributedlabel-to-set-two-color-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521972/ios-using-tttattributedlabel-to-set-two-color-text) link for reference.